# Rails 6 image not showing in Heroku staging

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, heroku, assets, ruby-on-rails-6

I am defining some background images in the Welcome Controller, so depending on the view the image changes, in local is working but when i deploy in Heroku, it stopped showing the background image.

the app is in rails 6, the images and being taken from the assets folder.
the background image is loading in the courses view

Header partial, where I am loading the images:

```
<section style="background-image:url(<%= @background_image%>)" class="banner <%= 'short-banner' unless @index%>" role="banner">
```

Welcome controller:

```
  def index
    @background_image = '/assets/computer_low_res.jpg'
    @title = 'BOGOTA BOOTCAMP'
  end

  def learn
    @background_image = '/assets/two_computers_low_res.jpg'
    @title = 'Try some Ruby'
  end

  def courses
    @background_image = 'https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/bogota-bootcamp/about-program.jpg'
    @title = 'Courses'
  end
```

Comment: Does visiting the `courses` url, shows the image ?

Comment: yes that one show, probably because is hosted in AWS

Answer (score 0):

Check `env/production.rb`

This line and make it `true` and deploy it again. Let me know...

```
#config.public_file_server.enabled = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?
config.public_file_server.enabled = true
```

Comment: did not work, this appears in the heroku console: 2019-09-23T19:05:12.453510+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/our_team.jpg" host=bogota-bootcamp-staging.herokuapp.com request_id=e5aaedcc-801d-42b7-aa02-df6fd13e0f36 fwd="181.48.147.210" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3ms status=404 bytes=1781 protocol=https

Answer (score 0):

solved!
change the header:

```
<section style="background-image:url(<%= asset_path(@background_image)%>)" class="banner <%= 'short-banner' unless @index%>" role="banner">
```

controller:

```
 def index
    @background_image = 'computer_low_res.jpg'
    @title = 'BOGOTA BOOTCAMP'
  end

  def learn
    @background_image = 'two_computers_low_res.jpg'
    @title = 'Try some Ruby'
  end

  def courses
    @background_image = 'https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/bogota-bootcamp/about-program.jpg'
    @title = 'Courses'
  end
```